# Maven : Getting issue while using MOJO

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a framework where I have multiple classes and one of my class is a mojo class which gets some data from a different class and then pass that data to some other class for execution.
The first time when I use command **mvn clean install** I would get error - Could not find artifact com.io:MyDataProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Then I have to comment out the second plugin section inside build tag as shown below and again use command **mvn clean install** which would then install my plugin and once installed I would then uncomment the commented code again  so that I can use my installed plugin which executes the mojo and then everything runs fine.

Issue is if I would share my project with other team members they have to do the same steps which I don't want. I need something like using mvn clean install would install my plugin and can execute my mojo at the same time.

```
    @Mojo(name = "dependency-counter", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
    public class DependencyCounterMojo extends AbstractMojo {
        
            public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ....Mojo execution begins.... $$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                GenerateFeature ob=new GenerateFeature();
                ob.getData();
            }
        }
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyDataProject</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dependency-counter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: You are trying to add a plugin to the POM of this plugin?

Comment: i have a maven project and under src/main/java I have all my framework related classes + mojo class and only one POM file which is of this maven project only.

Comment: you can create modular project, and build the plugin as module first, and your project as second module

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate projects or modules:

- One for the plugin, containing the mojo and the POM for the plugin.
- One for your framework, where the POM lists the plugin under `<plugins>`.

You cannot list the plugin in the same POM that produces the plugin.

You might also consider not putting the plugin into the POM at all, but run it on command line.

Comment: yes i was thinking to go with multi module approach with the steps you mentioned but one problem I m getting is I have to call a function inside Mojo(Module1) which is present in a class in my framework (Module2) . But as I execute mvn clean install in Parent module then mojo output the same result everytime.Is there a issue in calling a class from some other project inside mojo?

Comment: No, that is no problem. Make sure you define the correct dependency with version `${project.version}`

Comment: So you're trying to build the plugin first, but it depends on the second module containing the framework, which is not yet builded and references the plugin in it's pom, that's kind of a cyclic dependency, can you post the entire pom ?